# Using PowerPlatform type Service Connections in Pipeline task

Tags: azure-devops

In Azure DevOps: Service Connections, there is an option for PowerPlatform. This service connection type  takes a ClientSecret and an App Id to access a Dynamics 365 instance.

This is then used by Microsoft's Power Platform Tools to access online Dynamics 365 instances from a build pipeline.

What type of task input is this? I have tried:

- "type": "connectedService:PowerPlatform"
- "type": "connectedService:PowerPlatformSPN"
- "type": "connectedService:SPN"

(based on the YAML for the Microsoft Power Platform Tools)

I haven't been able to find any documentation on this type of Service connection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of the task input is `powerplatform-spn`

`"type": "connectedService:powerplatform-spn"`

It seems it is not mentioned in the documentation. However, you can get the type via azure devops rest api. [Endpoints - Get Service Endpoints By Names](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/serviceendpoint/endpoints/get%20service%20endpoints%20by%20names?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1)

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/serviceendpoint/endpoints?endpointNames={endpointNames}&api-version=6.1-preview.4
```

See below screenshot:

[image]